# How to read POST data from node JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I send some json data using node JS and curl.  I use this syntax specifically to increase the max buffer size, but I don't know how to receive my data in PHP.

**NodeJS**

```
var a = (JSON.stringify({key1: "val1", key2 : "val2"}));
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var execute = function(command, callback) {
  exec(command, {maxBuffer: 1024 * 1000}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {callback(error, stdout);});
};

execute("curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '" + a +"' 'https://www.e-cotiz.com/api-payment-test/export/test.php'", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  // if(err) throw err;
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
  if (error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
  $headers = apache_request_headers();

  $jsonStr = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
  $data = json_decode($jsonStr,true);

  print_r($data);
?>
```

I have two questions:

- Are my JS code and the syntax to send JSON correct ?
- How to modify my PHP code to receive my data ?

Comment: print_r($_REQUEST)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure how it works from Node, but assuming your `a` variable was an object that looked like this...

```
var a = {
    key1: 'val1',
    key2: 'val2'
};
```

Then PHP would access the information like so...

```
$value1 = $_POST['a']['key1'];
$value2 = $_POST['a']['key2'];
```